# What is the mythos behind Kult?

Tags: kult

I'm aware that the older RPG, Kult, was loosely based on Gnostic thought and mysticism. I find the overall idea and mechanics fairly interesting and am looking into building a port of the system over to a more modern RPG. However, there doesn't seem to be much information on the actual mythos beyond the basic game conceit (fallen angels vs angels loyal to the absent demiurge with humans stuck in the middle).

What is the larger storyline (mythos/metaplot) behind the original Kult and is there any in-print material that would support fleshing out my understanding of the storyline?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Gnostic.

The world is an Illusion, which is unravelling to reveal an even darker backdrop which the players must deal with. This Illusion was created by the Demiurge to hold humanity prisoner and to prevent mankind from regaining the divinity it once had. In the game's cosmology humans can regain their lost divine status through a game concept called Awakening in which characters with an extremely high or low mental balance are no longer restrained by the rules of the Illusion. These are not nice people you're playing.

Cosmology is kabbalistic. There are Archons and Death Angels. The demiurge has disappeared and the inevitable power struggle is going on.

[The Abyss](http://www.kult-rpg.org/blog) website is probably one of the better places to start.

Answer (score 3):

Reality as we know it is a thin skin stretched over the truth, which human beings can perceive through the use of magic or pushing themselves to their moral limits — both "good" and "evil." This false world is preserved and maintained by the *lictors*, who were once our playmates and now serve as our jailers.

Answer (score 0):

I was "introduced" to Kult vis a vis a buy searching for the game of the same name aka chambers of the sci mutant priestess.  I did a cursory glance at what a search engine had to say about it and was underwhelmed.  I was never much into role playing games.  I was more of the drummer that hung out with musicians.  RPG's based on christianity is/was a big turn off.  Ironic is it not that that I am brought to dealing with your question.  If you ignore what the other commenters say for a moment and focus on the theme of the abyss.  You'll get a deeper answer.

People may have gotten themselves into trouble with Kult.  What happens to those great second dates you never hear from again?  I pretend they died.  Liber OS ABYSMI vel. DAATH leaves little to the imagination but enough to "fill in the blanks".  The abyss here is daath which is not really part of the kabbalistic tree of life.  Even this is a veil.  There are layers of the illusion.  One, the so-called tree of life.  All judgements are "false" contemporaneous to a system of classification.  In buddhism, the myth of Gautama attaining enlightenment at the base of the Bodhi tree, the tree called Sal, the tree of solomon.  Hints at Solomons gate.

Ordinarily we can say that the Lotus world is thus the womb but it is not.  The fetus is the common range of all things, it is both reigon and domain.  Again, this is misdirection.  Its not the womb of the mother, or the fetus, its the homunculus.  More commonly known as doppleganger.  The lotus world is the abyss.  On the other side of the abyss is "the other shore".  What is needed is a vehicle to carry us there.

The bodhi tree literally is thusly, false.  It has nothing to do with enlightenment.  Likewise the "tree of life" is simply a construction of complementary postulates.  Daath is not part of this.  Postulates that hide or are the veil or the illusion are hidden and are like a signpost covering a keypad that turns off the holodeck if you will.  This is daath.  Not the hidden postulates but the keypad.

Daath is the end of the game.  The game is "hide and seek" if you will.  Different postulates take different roles to the game.  But the guardians if you will is a sign that says "Pit bull with aids" and a scary rent-a-cop posted.  Does that make sense?  In poker there is a saying, never tell when you spot a tell.  In other words the veil is you know something but keep it to yourself.

The whole game or illusion is maintained by all those in collusion but the game itself exists because those that are not players are making everyone "play by their rules".  Its not their game really and its not their rules.  They are not mere victims or dissillusioned or even cynical.  They are "company men" behind desks in a government office building giving you the run around.

Thus also there are dimensions to Daath.  The most obvious is what is being hidden at any given time within the game.  The higher dimension is what disconnects from the whole thing and is the very thing the gatekeepers, the watchers, ect fear most.  Disintegration or Disillusion.

Very primordial indeed but rather silly from a psycho-philosophical sense.  Its very much liken to a small ugly mexican dog chasing its own tail around in a circle.

Comment: -1 it's quite hard to make any sense of this answer.

Comment: @Vatine Ironically, it does illustrate the mythos behind Kult quite well, as if from the perspective of an in-fiction NPC…

Comment: That it does, but that isn't very helpful for someone looking at this question and its answers.

Comment: I don't know, I think it gave me a pretty good idea of what the mythos is like. Some things are better experienced than explained.

Answer (score 0):

Kults basic idea is when Nietschze said God is dead he was positing a truth that everyone else had missed. God has buggered off...
Reality is falling apart and the devil who should be really happy is actually upset he didn't get to win. From there Gnostic grab basket of ideas which work well as long as you don't give them more thought..
Kult is a nicer game scene from a distance and it becomes increasingly confusing as you try and get towards it... There is also a ongoing issue that the game world requires stasis and really everyone is fighting for that stasis...

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the stasis angle (both the world requiring it and everyone fighting for it)?